# Android Java Fingerpaint clear all function?

Tags: java, android

So just messing about the Fingerpaint demo in the SDK and trying to implement a "clear all" function rather than using the eraser tool. And I added the code below which works but only after you touch the screen. E.g. I scribble a bit on the screen hit the "clear all" button but scribble is still there until I hit the screen with my finger than it disappears. How can I get the screen to update immediately upon hitting the button? Thanks ahead of time.

```
    private void clearAll() {             
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);          
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);          
     }
```

Comment: Please post your answer if you solve it. I need it urgent.

Comment: `canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);`

Answer (score 1):

To clear the canvas, it's probably best just to call [`Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawColor%28int%29) or use some other color. The way you're doing it seems to work too, but it's also 1) creating extra objects, and 2) the new canvas isn't being used until `onDraw()` is getting called again.

I think calling `drawColor()` will automatically invalidate the canvas and force a redraw. If it doesn't, or if you want to stick to using a new `Bitmap` and new `Canvas`, then try adding a call to [`View.invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29).

Comment: Same thing is happening it seems

Answer (score 0):

try setting a flag when "clear all" is clicked.

Then in `onDraw`, if this flag is true, clear the canvas.

```
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    this.mCanvas.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,width, height),paint);
```

onDraw is called by the android UI framework and that's where changes occur.

Comment: That seemed to produce the same results